# Can I download the new version and burn it to a CD and install it without reformating the hard drive?

Tags: upgrade

I was upgrading from version 11 to version 12 and during the upgrade it stopped processing giving a message of "stopped processing due to too many errors". Now the operating system is corrupt and does not function, no cursor, no control at all. Can I download the new version and burn it to a CD and install it without reformating the hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

Yes

> Since Hardy it is possible to reinstall Ubuntu without losing the content of the /home folder (the folder that contains program settings, internet bookmarks, emails and all your documents, music, videos and other user files). This can be done even if /home is not on a separate partition.

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation